# Label for Radiobutton SIlverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

New to SIlverlight. Trying to add radio button. It looks ok, however I want to add a label to this field.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Option1, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Option1"/>
  <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Option2, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource trueToFalse}}" Content="Option2" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The above code shows output like this:
[image]

However I want a label in front of it like this. 
[image]
Usually for other controls, if Data binding is specified, it takes the field name. It is not showing up like that for radio button. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to add a label or TextBlock to the StackPanel.

If you need the name to be dynamic then you can add binding to the Content or Text properties (respectively)